# Send POST body parametres in JS

Tags: javascript, json, post

I'm trying to send a parameter to an API and the parameter has to be sent as post body. The Authorization header is required to send the API key.

- How can I add a post body request with data being "server_id: 12345" ?
- How can I print the JSON the API gives me onto my webpage?

```
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", PowerOff);
function PowerOff() {
  "";

  console.log("Doing");

  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "CrocodileZebraGiraffe",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `body` data type must match "Content-Type" header. 
To receive the json you receive there is standart `then` move.
So in the end you will get something like:

```
var data = {server_id: 12345} //you can create it inside the function if it doesn't change
function PowerOff() {
  "";

  console.log("Doing");

  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "CrocodileZebraGiraffe",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(response=>{
    console.log('Success: ', response);
    //if you want to access this response later, you have to assign it to some variable
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add new `key` called `body` & set it with whatever data you want as a stringified object:

```
const data = {server_id: "12345" };
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "CrocodileZebraGiraffe",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then((res)=> {
   // do whatever you need with result
});
```